# Implementation of content's update via InAppPurchase

Tags: in-app-purchase

My app has some downloadable (from my server) guides and maps, and user could buy them with InAppPurchase. I would like to update these guides once a month or like that, so users could buy the updates with half price. How should I implement InAppPurchase logic?

I mean, the most obvious solution for me is to create InApp's for every update. When user wants to update guide, he asks server for update's InApp ID, then purchase it, and download it from server. The previous guide will be deleted. The question: is that logic good? And won't Apple reject my app because I delete the content the user has paid for? (even I replace it with the newer one)

Or maybe there are more correct solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to delete the previous ones?

Your logc is ok, but the only change i would make is to let the user choose, if he wants to delete the previous content or not, by asking him every time he buys a new one.

That wouldn't make him angry and would prevent a rejection by Apple.

Comment: customer wants the deleting of previous guides and I think this is consistent to delete the guide after update. So does Apple reject the app in that case or not?

Comment: If i were a customer, i wouldn't want to to do that)How do you know, what every customer wants?)

Comment: I mean, the man that make me an order to do that app, not "user". So you did not answer the question :)

Comment: Apple really doesn't care of what Afisha's managers want to do, they care about iphone users, so, since it may make them angry, it's likely that they can reject your app.

Comment: that is what I needed to hear, thanks then.
btw keeping unnecessary guides on device even if they were bought is not good, as for me

Comment: Never Delete without asking the user - the great rule of every developer)